# SonarQube project not updating from Sonar Runner

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've provisioned three projects, two of which update as expected each time Jenkins deploys to the dev environment. However, while the third job populates with the initial results, each subsequent run does not update the project despite successful SonarRunner execution. (I've scrubbed some of the names and paths).

Here is the failing job project file:
    # required metadata
    sonar.projectKey=xxxxxxx
    sonar.projectName=xxxxxxx
    sonar.projectVersion=1.0

```
# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src

# paths to exclude
#sonar.exclusions=

sonar.scm.disabled=true

sonar.javascript.mode=skip
sonar.css.mode=skip

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Here is the console output from Jenkins:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_71 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: xxxxxxxx/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: xxxxxxx/workspace/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
12:29:29.558 INFO  - Load global repositories
12:29:29.784 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=228ms
12:29:29.786 INFO  - Server id: 20150522113240
12:29:29.788 INFO  - User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
12:29:29.797 INFO  - Install plugins
12:29:30.091 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
12:29:30.112 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
12:29:31.619 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
12:29:33.037 INFO  - Load project repositories
12:29:34.129 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=1092ms
12:29:34.130 INFO  - Load project settings
12:29:34.834 INFO  - Load technical debt model
12:29:34.863 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
12:29:36.001 INFO  - -------------  Scan www.XXXXXXXXX.com-XXXXXXXX
12:29:36.005 INFO  - Load module settings
12:29:36.214 INFO  - Load rules
12:29:37.422 INFO  - Base dir: xxxxx/workspace
12:29:37.422 INFO  - Working dir: xxxxx.sonar
12:29:37.422 INFO  - Source paths: src
12:29:37.423 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
12:29:37.423 INFO  - Index files
12:29:38.342 INFO  - 254 files indexed
12:29:43.048 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
12:29:43.048 INFO  - Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
12:29:43.524 WARN  - ----------------------------------------------------------------
12:29:43.524 WARN  - Sonargraph: Skipping project xxxxx, since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
12:29:43.524 WARN  - ----------------------------------------------------------------
12:29:43.526 INFO  - JIRA issues sensor will not run as some parameters are missing.
12:29:43.541 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor
12:29:44.015 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
12:29:44.017 INFO  - 238 source files to be analyzed
12:29:55.279 INFO  - 238/238 source files analyzed
12:29:55.278 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 11263 ms
12:29:55.279 WARN  - Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer. The org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DependenciesVisitor@7cd07967, org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedPrivateMethodCheck@43b7ee4b, org.sonar.java.checks.RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck@607da0a8 are disabled.
12:29:55.280 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
12:29:55.280 INFO  - 0 source files to be analyzed
12:29:55.280 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 0 ms
12:29:55.280 INFO  - 0/0 source files analyzed
12:29:55.466 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=11925ms
12:29:55.467 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
12:29:55.501 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=34ms
12:29:55.501 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
12:29:55.505 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=4ms
12:29:55.506 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
12:30:29.395 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=33889ms
12:30:29.395 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
12:30:29.404 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=9ms
12:30:29.404 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
12:30:29.427 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=23ms
12:30:29.427 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor
12:31:14.500 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor (done) | time=45073ms
12:31:14.500 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor
12:31:15.041 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor (done) | time=541ms
12:31:15.041 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
12:31:15.728 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=687ms
12:31:15.729 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
12:31:15.729 INFO  - SCM Sensor is disabled
12:31:15.729 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
12:31:15.729 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
12:31:15.729 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
12:31:15.731 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
12:31:16.474 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for xml
12:31:16.476 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=747ms
12:31:16.477 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
12:31:16.520 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-05-22)
12:31:16.524 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-04-26, analysis of Fri May 22 11:08:22 CDT 2015)
12:31:17.192 INFO  - Execute decorators...
12:32:58.147 INFO  - Store results in database
12:33:12.805 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 4585ms, dir size=64 MB
12:33:14.429 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 1624ms, zip size=9 MB
12:33:16.335 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 1905ms
12:33:16.336 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse xxxxxx
12:33:16.336 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3:47.493s
Final Memory: 37M/2167M
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell what might be going on.  Did you maybe accidentally not update the sonar.projectKey on one of the projects?  That could cause 2 of the builds to update one project on the dashboard making it look like 1 is not publishing.

Comment: There can be only two possible explanations: either the projectKey is not the good one or the populated SonarQube DB is not the good one.

Comment: I completely deleted the non-updating project and recreated it with a different projectKey. I modified the Jenkins job to use the new key and it has continued to exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: What does "the populated SonarQube DB is not the good one." mean exactly? How would one recover from this?

Comment: Can you spell out the directory structure of the projects and how they differ from the working ones to the non working ones?

Comment: Hi dude,
I also had some issue last time.
I use community version, so I could not manage the pull request and branch name.
I installed locally, so every time you want to update the code, you must run manually sonar-scanner.bat xxxxx
And new codes menu will update automatically after you run that command.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issue last time.
I use community version, so I could not manage the pull request and branch name.
I installed locally, so every time you want to update the code, you must run manually sonar-scanner.bat xxxxx
And new codes menu will update automatically after you run that command.